# What did I wrong with my Ajax code?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I want to add items in my listbox when button is clicked, then, it has to return the value which has added in listbox through ajax.

Here the code, what I tried.

```
$('#right').click(function () {
    alert("Start process");
    var item = "testing";

    $.ajax({
        url: 'ReportSalesAll.aspx/setRightListBoxitems',
        method: 'post',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        data: '{listItems:' + item + '}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
           alert("result = " + data.d.text)
        },
        failure: function (response) {
           alert(response.d);
        },
        error: function (error) {
           alert("Error = "+error);
        }
    });
});
```

Aspx code:

```
<input type="button" id="right" value=">>" />

<asp:ListBox ID="lstRight" runat="server" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="100%" Height="220"></asp:ListBox>
```

Back end code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string setRightListBoxitems(string listItems)
{
   ReportSalesAll rs = new ReportSalesAll();
   rs.lstRight.Items[0].Text = listItems;
   rs.lstRight.Items[0].Value = "faisal "+listItems ;
   return rs.lstRight.Items[0].Text;
}
```

> I got the error when I run `Error = [Object object]`
>
> readyState:4,
>   status:500
>   statusText:Internal server error
>   responseText: Message: "invalid JSON primitive: testing.",StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()

Comment: Instead of ``alert("Error = "+error);`` use ``console.log("Error:", error);`` - that way you can actually see what error response the server returns.

Comment: have you tried to debug your code in browser? this can provide you the error and its objects

Comment: @mpf82 Now i have updated. please check the error

Comment: @NMathur please check now

Comment: Does the server respond with valid JSON? You also have a typo in ``'applciation/json'``.

Comment: are you able to reach at "setRightListBoxitems" (backend code) through break point ..

Comment: @mpf82 wait. its different error after i update that `application/json` please wait i will update

Comment: @NMathur I don't understand. What is break point?.

Comment: in C# code .. go to this line ..public static string setRightListBoxitems(string listItems) . .and press f9 .. then run your code .. you will be able to debug you code .

Comment: @NMathur It doesn't make difference in error. when i press f9 I can see red in that line, when i run it, it shows the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "invalid JSON primitive: testing.",StackTrace":" at ...

**Problem :** is with this part of code. `data: '{listItems:' + item + '}'` You are not constructing the JSON properly.

The above code return the data as `"{listItems:testing}"` which is invalid JSON. Note there is no `" "` around the string `testing` which is what the error says.

**Solution:** use `JSON.stringify()` rather than manually getting your hands dirty. Replace the above line of code with

```
data: JSON.stringify({listItems:item});
```

This returns the data as `"{"listItems":"testing"}"` and Its a valid JSON.

Comment: I changed as you mentioned. This is the error `"{"Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","StackTrace":"   at DevExpressDemo.ReportSalesAll.setRightListBoxitems(String listItems) in d:\\Faisal Private\\DevExpressDemo\\DevExpressDemo\\ReportSalesAll.aspx.cs:line 181","ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException"}"`

Comment: @mohamedfaisal good... now the control hits the server.. which is resolved.. the next error might be because of this `rs.lstRight.Items[0].Text = listItems;`.. you have initialized `rs` but not `lstRight` in it.. can you confirm

Comment: `listItems` is parameter. even I tried to return direct string like this `return "Result working"`. Still the same error what i mentioned above

Comment: @mohamedfaisal I meant `lstRight` .... ie: `rs.lstRight`.. Also the error is from your c# code.. now ajax issue is fixed

Comment: yes you are right. those line are error. but the result shows like `result = {"d":"testing"}`. how should i get the value\

Comment: @mohamedfaisal you can Covert the  JSON to object.. by using libraries like newtonsoft.. Also if you are just passing one string then all this drama of JSON is not required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131252/discussion-between-mohamed-faisal-and-rajshekar-reddy).